# Differentiability of the Fourier series of $(x^2-1)^2$ on [-1,1)

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, periodic-functions

I have calculated the Fourier series as given in the question to be

$$f(x)=\frac{8}{15}+\frac{48}{\pi^4}\sum_{1}^{\infty }(-1)^{n+1}\frac{\cos(n\pi x)}{n^4}$$
I am asked to comment on the differentiability and the order of its terms in the Fourier series as $n\to\infty$
Is the following argument correct, 
the periodic extension of $f''(x)$ belongs to $C(\mathbb{R})$ and $f''(x)$ is continuously differentiable but the periodic extension of $f'''(x)$ is not in $C(\mathbb{R})$ so the fourth derivative will not converge to its Fourier series when differentiated term wise. So it is 3 times differentiable and the terms are $O(1/n^4)$.

Comment: What does $C(\Bbb{R})$ represent? The set of continuous $\Bbb{R}\rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ functions?

Comment: Yes it represents continuous everywhere functions on R.